# Saiku,Mondrian performance degrades with large amount of data

Tags: olap, mondrian, saiku

We are using mondrian olap schema with saiku to analyse our records.We are using star schema model.We have one fact table which contains around 3000000 records. We have four dimension tables timestamp,rank,path and domain. Timestamp is almost unique for each entry . Now after deploying schema in saiku when we are performing analysis saiku takes a lot of time to return results. It takes 10 minutes to fetch 3000 records and if number of records are more than 50000 saiku dies.Please suggest me on what should I do in order to boost performance of saiku and mondrian.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad. What have you tried so far? It sounds like you haven't designed your warehouse in an OLAP friendly way; why haven't you structured your time dimension in a hierarchal fashion?

Comment: @Luc.. Thanks for response . I have designed my timestamp dimension in a hierarchial manner with 3 levels year,month and days.Designed my olap schema using pentaho schema workbench and have no idea about olap friendly designing .Please suggest me regarding designing issues .

Answer (score 2):

You can easily figure out if this is database issue or saiku/mondrian problem:

1. Enable sql logging facility in `saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml` (uncomment section below `Special Log File specifically for Mondrian SQL Statements` text
2. Restart server
3. Do couple of typical analysis in Saiku
4. Get used queries from log
5. Analyze performance of queries directly in database (e.g. for PostgreSQL there is `explain analyze` command)

If performance of queries is as slow as in Saiku then you have identified your problem.

Btw. If you really have dimension for timestamp (by second?) than you should consider splitting it into two dimensions with days and seconds.

Comment: Well, I identified that my problem is slow SQL queries which Saiku generate. How I should fix it? Can I change strategy of saiku's SQL generator?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what is your particular problem.

Two things helped us when we struggle with saiku performance problems:

- indices on all fields and sometimes their combinations that may be
  used as dimensions - helps like everywhere in DB
- we avoided joines with other tables denormalizing our data